# values of tableview cell are mixing

Tags: swift, uitableview

when i tap on the accept button in a cell of view controller its always sends the same value to next controller

```
class FriendRequestTVC: UITableViewCell {
    struct GB{
   static var senderID = 0
}
```

this is how im saving response

```
class RequestResponseVC : UIViewController{
var requests:[[String:Any]] = [[String:Any]] ()
switch response.result {
        case .success:
            if let responseValue = response.value as! [String:Any]? {
            if let responseData = responseValue["data"] as! [[String:Any]]?{
            self.requests = responseData
            self.tableView.reloadData()
                     }
                 }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! FriendRequestTVC
    let data = self.requests[indexPath.row]
    FriendRequestTVC.GB.senderID  = self.requests[indexPath.row]["id"] as! Int
    return cell
}
```

it always sends the same value to the var in struct

**suggest me how i save the senderID that it remains different for every cell according to their array.**

Comment: You get the same value because senderID is declared static so it is a single global property. Remove static and assign cell.GB.senderID instead. (I am not sure why you need a struct to hold the property, can't it be a property of FriendRequestTVC?)

Comment: Right, remove the static and the struct and change to `cell.senderId = self.requests[indexPath.row]["id"] as! Int`

Comment: You have already asked that question and gotten some answers as well.